# Menu for bevel edges

Tags: interface

Is there any way to show a menu of the tools in the middle of the screen, like its done in 3ds max. I mean, for example, when you choose the tool Bevel Edges It show the menu in the bottom of the screen. But i want this menu will appear in the middle of the screen where i can to select specific parameters by clicking the mouse button instead of clicking keyboard buttons.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible at the moment: if you start bevelling using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> you are forced to use the keyboard-based workflow.

However, you can use the bevel *tool* (green icon in the left-side toolbar) instead of the bevel operation, which gives you access to some more options (not all the shortcuts though).

In combination with the "tool settings" header, it allows you to change the options right *before* starting your bevel operation:

---

[image]

Actions performed in the above gif:

- Edit mode, select your edge
- Select the Bevel tool
- If it's not active already, activate the "Tool Settings" header by right-clicking on the 3D Viewport header
- Adjust the setting
- Hold down the mouse button and drag

---

Alternatively to the "Tool settings" toolbar, you can display a "Tool properties" panel in the Properties area.

Comment: Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible!

Preferences -> Keymap -> Tool Keys

Change "Immediate" to "Active Tool"

[image: Preferences -> Keymap -> Tool Keys = Active Tool]